# Excel VBA, UnHiding Sheets in array, Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, show-hide, worksheet

I'm trying to unhide specific sheets using an array, but get an Run-time error '13'.
It's this specific line of code that gives me the error:

```
Worksheets(WS).Visible = True
```

I managed to hide the specific sheets using an array (I refer to the CodeNames of the sheets to avoid future refering problems), see code below:

```
Sub Hide_sheets_By_CodeName()

Dim Ws_Array As Variant
Set Ws_Array = Sheets(Array(Tiger.Name, Dog.Name, Cat.Name))
Ws_Array.Visible = False

End Sub
```

To Unhide them I've read that you have to loop through each sheet in the array. I have used this code for that (and here I get the error):

```
Sub UnHide_sheets_By_CodeName()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Ws_Array As Variant

Set Ws_Array = Sheets(Array(Tiger.Name, Dog.Name, Cat.Name))

For Each WS In Ws_Array
    Worksheets(WS).Visible = True

Next

End Sub
```

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Just use `Worksheets(WS.Name).Visible = True` in the for loop

Comment: Thanks Storax! Now I see, it now works like a charm :) Happy easter (or else have a nice weekend if you don't celebrate) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WS_Array is an object of Type Sheets, i.e. a member is a sheet. Therefore `Worksheets(WS).Visible = True` runs into error 13 as `Worksheets(name of sheet)` expects a string and not an object.

Either you change your for loop to

```
For Each WS In Ws_Array    
    Worksheets(WS.Name).Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next
```

or  to

```
For Each WS In Ws_Array
    WS.Visible = xlSheetVisible    
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining how things fit together in an easy-to-understand way. I feel I've learned something that I will benefit from in the time coming :)